# How to execute adb backup command in JS(can be node JS) using adbkit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, adb

I am currently using adbkit as library to execute adb command in my JS file.

Description about adbkit(source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/adbkit/v/1.0.7)

**adbkit** is a pure Node.js client for the Android Debug Bridge server. It can be used either as a library in your own application, or simply as a convenient utility for playing with your device.

Most of the adb command line tool's functionality is supported (including pushing/pulling files, installing APKs and processing logs).

I want my JS application to take backup of connected device using adb backup command. So far i am able to get device info and the list of files with the help of following code

```
client.listDevices()
.then(function(devices) {
return Promise.map(devices, function(device) {
    return client.readdir(device.id, '/sdcard')
    .then(function(files) {
        files.forEach(function(file) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            //console.log(device);
            console.log('[%s] Found file "%s"', device.id, file.name);
        }
        })
    })
})
})
```

Please help me regarding backing up the device data using adbkit library in JS.